# How to use Xargs in TCL with Exec

Tags: tcl

How can i use Xargs in with Exec in TCL,

For example,

```
xargs -I{} basename {}
```

I have xargs statement like this, how can i use that in TCL with Exec,

```
exec xargs -I{} basename {}
```

It is not working properly.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, `{}` is special to Tcl (it's standard Tcl metasyntax) so you'd need to quote it with double quotes or a backslash in *some* cases. And it's not harmful otherwise:

```
exec xargs -I{} basename "{}"
```

```
exec xargs -I\{\} basename \{\}
```

It's particularly the one on its own that causes problems; Tcl thinks that means pass an empty string as an argument there (which is legal, but not what you really meant). Remember: Tcl's syntax is *not* the Unix shell's syntax. They might appear superficially similar, but they're really different.

Comment: @Axit, or you could just use a different placeholder: `exec xargs -IFOO basename FOO`